# Cannot identify how one website is redirecting to another

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, dns

I have a strange problem which I can't identify the cause of.

There are two servers which host two different sites. Both sites are PHP-based apps.

**Server 1 (Ubuntu)**

https://app.site1.com

Server has SSL enabled for this site. This site works fine.

**Server 2 (Red Hat)**

http://app.site2.com

Server does not have SSL enabled for this site.

---

Here's what happens:

- If I access site 2 on http:// it works fine.
- If I access site 2 on https:// it redirects to site 1 on the other server.

Now obviously there is something telling this subdomain to go to the other site when served via SSL.

**What I have checked:**

- All virtual hosts on both servers
- All DNS records on both servers
- All Site 2 website code
- Site 2 .htaccess files
- Using uncached browsers

There is NOTHING on either of the servers, that I can find, telling site 2 to redirect to site 1, only on HTTPS. Now obviously I don't expect anybody to find the problem directly because you can't see my entire server configuration, but **I am looking for suggestions as to where else this redirect could come from**.

Comment: May be code on `site2` server

Comment: I agree with @anubhava it could be done with code or plugin depending on what you are running. Many people use PHP (or other languages) to redirect.

Comment: @PanamaJack Both are PHP-based but we wrote the code ourselves and know everything well. There is 100% no code that says to redirect. I have even searched everything just to make sure.

Comment: Have you checked the network traffic, ie. do you see a 301, 302 or 200 response etc.? Or no response (could be proxied)? A 200 response would perhaps suggest client-side code... JS / META Refresh. Does the same occur in all browsers... Chrome, Firefox and IE?

Comment: @w3d Same in any browser, different machine, no cache, etc. There is 100% no client side redirect such as JS or meta refresh. Note the site only redirects on HTTPS. HTTP will stay there, so my initial thought was DNS problem but there are no DNS records for it.

Comment: If it was a DNS problem it would affect both HTTP _and_ HTTPS. Do you see the redirect response (3xx) in the network traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could understand this if you had site1 and site2 hosted on the same server.

Basically if you have no config set up for a second vhost on https (port 443) then Apache will fall back to first vhost by default.

So if both sites were in same Apache config then that might be it. But you say they are not. Are you sure you are not serving both sites from the same server (perhaps with a copy in the other server)? Are the IP addresses the same? Are there any load balancers or CDN infrastructure in front of both servers?

Also you say "If I access site 2 on https:// it redirects to site 1 on the other server." Can you explain more about what happens here? If you go to site 2 and do not have https set up then how can this even respond to this request? What certificate is being presented to that initial request (i.e. **before** the redirect)? Is it the site1 certificate? And if so then do you get a certificate error in the browser (since its presenting the wrong certificate for the site you requested) that you have to click through before you get redirected? Or is the cert valid for both sites?

You can also use this openssl command to see what the server returns (and in particular which certificate it returns):

```
openssl s_client -connect app.site2.com:443
```

It would also be handy to look at the browsers developer tools and see how exactly the redirect is happening. In Chrome press F12, go to Network tab, click on preserve log and then go to https://app.site2.com/. What is the first request? Is it a 301 or 302 (i.e. Server side redirect)? Or if it's a 200 followed by the https://app.site1.com/ then some piece of JavaScript must have caused the redirect.

Once you have answered those questions it may be possible to provide further guidance.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. They are definitely on separate servers, no copies. No load balancing or CDN. Site 2 on HTTPS presents certificate from its own server, not from site 1. 301 redirect then occurs which sends it to [https://app.site1.com](https://app.site1.com) and returns a 302 site found. Certificate for site 1 is working correctly.

Comment: How can that be when site2 does not have https and so presumably does not have a certificate?!?! Somewhere that certificate MUST be configured.

Comment: It's not a valid certificate, presumably because it's not configured properly. There isn't a virtual host for site2:443, but the question is more where the redirect is coming from.

Comment: I would say the question is more where this certificate is coming from? That will then presumably be the same place your redirect is coming from. Something must be listening on site2:443 for that cert and redirect to be served.